# SSRS Passing in Expression without using Placeholder Properties

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using SSRs to generate letters. The body of my letters is stored in my SQL server 2012 database. Is it possible to specify an expression in my body column in sql and recognize it in SSRS as an expression?

Example. SQL column contains.  The name of the business is =first(Fields!Fieldname.Value, "DataSet").

In my textbox I have a placeholder [Body] which corresponds to my dataset. When I run the report I want it to show: The name of the business is Boen Shop but I get whatever is listed in SQL.

Comment: There is no way to `evaluate` text like an expression in SSRS, for that purpose you have to write your own parser.

Comment: That would be difficult to pull off. You would probably have better results making a search and replace in your database. However, I can think of a few nasty tricks that would allow you to replace custom tokens in your ssrs report.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I the best way to do this is create the body in ssrs instead of trying to pull everything from SQL.

Comment: You could write a stored procedure which does this using dynamic SQL, however this kind of dynamic generation is often more trouble than it is worth. If you explain further I might take time to pose an answer. Can you provide more examples?

Comment: This can be done quite easily using a data driven subscription; is that an option for you?

Comment: The only thing I can think of that SSRS will interpret on the fly is HTML in strings for formatting.